# VSCODE. How to open a file containing a variable or html tag by clicking it?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide, shortcut, functional-interface

I'm not sure how to describe the question properly. I used to use IDE tools such as IntelliJIdea. One of the useful functions from intelliJ was to open an external file by clicking an imported variable or component. I wonder if there is such functionality in vscode too. Although I tried looking up in the document, I couldn't find information about it. Does vscode really not have that convenient functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio Code does provide this feature.

If you hold down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key in VSCode and for example hover over a function call, a small info box appears (like shown below).

[image]

If you now click on it (while still holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>), VSCode automatically opens the corresponding file in a new tab and jumps to the line where the function was defined.

[image]

This works for variables, instances of classes etc. as well.